# Excel & GoogleSheets - Randbetween with condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with entered numbers (A:A) and specific dates (B:B). How could I randomly choose between entered number for each specific date?

In attached example, F2 should be random value between each number in A:A where B:B = 13.12.2022

[image]

I've tried playing with index and randbetween, but no result. I need formula for both Excel and Google Sheets.

Update: for Excel these do the trick

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$30;INDEX(LARGE(($B$1:$B$30=D2)*ROW($A$1:$A$30);ROW($A$1:$A$30));1+INT(RAND()*COUNTIF($B$1:$B$30;D2))))

=MAP(D2:D4,LAMBDA(a,LET(x,FILTER(A2:A11,B2:B11=a),@SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(COUNT(x))))))
```

But this doesnt work for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=MAP(D2:D4,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(FILTER(A2:A11,B2:B11=a),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(B:B,a)))))
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. Is it possible to convert this formula also for Google Sheets?

Comment: @ArtemyPanin, yes, but that means `LET()` can't be used. We can overcome this by using `RANDBETWEEN()` instead.